# Need to convert text files to Unicode from UTF8 in vbscript

Tags: text, unicode, encoding, utf-8, vbscript

I have a bunch of text files in a folder that I need to change the encoding on to Unicode and instead of manually opening the files and saving them as Unicode I would like to have a script to do this.

The files are currently in UTF-8 encoding and my extremely limited scripting abilities can't figure this one out.  I found the code below to convert to Unicode from ANSI and when I use this code it does convert it to Unicode but it messes up the characters so the conversion doesn't actually work.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\test")
Set oFiles = oFolder.files

For each file in oFiles
If Right(file.Name, 3) = "txt" Then
Set ANSIFile = fso.OpenTextFile(file.path, 1, False, False)
ANSIContent = ANSIFile.ReadAll
Set UNICODEFile = fso.OpenTextFile(file.path, 2, False, True)
UNICODEFile.Write ANSIContent
End If
Next
```

Comment: "Unicode" is not an encoding, you cannot change an actual file "to Unicode". What [actual encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Mapping_and_encodings) do you mean?

Comment: If you open a text file and select File-> Save As, one of the options for "Encoding" is "Unicode".  If I were to perform this task manually, I would open each file and save it as the same file with the encoding as Unicode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately VBScript doesn't support this kind of conversion by itself. You can use an [`ADODB.Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677486) object, though:

```
Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.Open
stream.Type = 2 'text
stream.Charset = "utf-8"
stream.LoadFromFile "C:\input.txt"
text = stream.ReadText
stream.Close

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\output.txt", 2, True, True)
f.Write text
f.Close
```

Or a little more streamlined:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.Open
stream.Type = 2 'text
stream.Charset = "utf-8"
stream.LoadFromFile "C:\input.txt"
fso.OpenTextFile("C:\output.txt", 2, True, True).Write stream.ReadText
stream.Close
```

If you want to replace the existing file you'll have to use the first version and use the same file for input and output. Use a loop like this to iterate over all files in a folder:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\source\folder").Files
  stream.Open
  stream.Type = 2 'text
  stream.Charset = "utf-8"
  stream.LoadFromFile f.Path
  text = stream.ReadText
  stream.Close

  fso.OpenTextFile(f.Path, 2, True, True).Write text
Next
```

Comment: Thanks!  That definitely worked, is there a way to do it to all text files in a folder and keep the same name (or just add a character to the end like "_U"?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Personally I don't have a preference for either `Write` or `WriteLine`. Is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - .WriteLine adds an EOL to the original (converted) content. With a bit of bad luck that breaks further processing (Split on ReadAll, computations based on # of lines) or causes systematic growth. Furthermore it violates the mantra ".WriteLine .ReadLine; .Write .Read[All]".

Comment: Not sure I'd call omitting [ADO Named Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678353(v=vs.85).aspx) *"streamlined"*.

Comment: `adTypeText` is not defined in VBScript, and I prefer to keep my code samples compact, so I tend to avoid (re-)defining symbolic constants.