# Convert wide character to multibyte in a batch or VBS script?

Tags: string, batch-file, type-conversion

Can anyone think of a way to convert a wide character file to a multibyte file in a batch or VBS script?

Let's say I have a file hello.txt that contains this text in wide character: "HELLO WORLD\r\n". In hex format that would be:

```
48 00 45 00 4C 00 4C 00 4F 00 20 00 57 00 4F 00 52 00 4C 00 44 00 0D 00 0A 00
```

I would like to convert it to a multi-byte file, i.e., to contain this:

```
48 45 4C 4C 4F 20 57 4F 52 4C 44 0D 0A
```

However, I need to do it either in a CMD file or a VBS script.  Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems you could do it using the same approach described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906280

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first:

```
<"UNICODE.TXT">"ASCII.TXT" FIND /V ""
```

---

second:

```
type "UNICODE.TXT">"ASCII.TXT"
```

Comment: Does this work without the BOM? I don't think the OP's content has the BOM.

Comment: @Endoro - I don't understand why this works, but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### In PowerShell

```
PowerShell "Get-Content -Encoding Unicode hello.txt | Out-File -Encoding ASCII out.txt"
```

**CharSets**

- Unicode = UCS-2 LE
- BigEndianUnicode = UCS-2 BE
- UTF8 = UTF-8 with BOM
- UTF7 = UTF-7
- ASCII = ASCII

[Get-Content](http://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html)

[Out-File](http://ss64.com/ps/out-file.html)