# vba convert msexcel table to json. Ending line not consistant

Tags: json, excel, vba

The sub below creates a json file from an Excel table that starts in cells(1,1). The problem is when I drag and drop the generated file in Visual Studio, I get the following message:

> The line endings in the following file are not consistent. Do you want
>   normalize the line endings?

How can I make this sub produce consistent line endings?

```
Sub CreateWksJON(mywksht As Worksheet, NbofFields As Integer, NbofElements As Integer)
Dim FilePath As String
Dim fieldData As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim objStream
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

objStream.Charset = "utf-8"
objStream.Open


FilePath = "E:\Git\ACWB-MSEcelWorksheetTOJson\" & mywksht.Name & ".json"

'Open FilePath For Output As #1


fieldData = "{" & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & """" & mywksht.Name & """" & ": {" & Chr(10) & Chr(13)



objStream.writetext fieldData

    fieldData = ""
For j = 1 To NbofFields
     i = 1

     fieldData = """" & mywksht.Cells(i, j).Value & """" & ": ["

    For i = 2 To NbofElements - 2
        If IsNumeric(mywksht.Cells(i, j).Value) Then

            fieldData = fieldData & mywksht.Cells(i, j).Value & ","
        Else
            fieldData = fieldData & """" & mywksht.Cells(i, j).Value & """" & ","

        End If
    Next i
        'add the last element of the field

        If IsNumeric(mywksht.Cells(i + 1, j).Value) Then

            fieldData = fieldData & mywksht.Cells(i + 1, j).Value
        Else
            fieldData = fieldData & """" & mywksht.Cells(i + 1, j).Value & """"

        End If


        If j = NbofFields Then

            fieldData = fieldData & "]" & Chr(10) & Chr(13)
        Else

            fieldData = fieldData & "]," & Chr(10) & Chr(13)
        End If

        objStream.writetext fieldData


Next j

objStream.writetext "}" & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & "}" & Chr(10) & Chr(13)

objStream.SaveToFile FilePath, 2


End Sub
```

Here is the table

```
Envelpope_ID    CG_MAC  CG_Imp  CG_SI   Weight_Imp  Weight_SI
1         20    875     22.225  71700   32522.58942
1         20    875     22.225  98000   44452.0748
1         28    900     22.86   129720  58840.03207
1         38    1000    25.4    129720  58840.03207
1         38    1000    25.4    119840  54358.53718
1         43    1200    30.48   102200  46357.16372
1         43    1200    30.48   94000   42637.7044
1         34    950     24.13   71700   32522.58942
1         20    875     22.225  71700   32522.58942
2         20    875     22.225  71700   32522.58942
2         20    875     22.225  98000   44452.0748
2         28    900     22.86   125000  56699.075
2         38    1000    25.4    125000  56699.075
2         38    1200    30.48   102200  46357.16372
2         43    1200    30.48   94000   42637.7044
2         43    950     24.13   71700   32522.58942
2         34    875     22.225  71700   32522.58942
```

Comment: Perhaps change `Chr(10) & Chr(13)` to vbCrLf.  I'm curious about your use of "ADODB.Stream" versus using a "Scripting.FileSystemObject" to create a Scripting.TextStream.  I'm not saying that it is wrong, just different from what I am used to doing. :)

Comment: I newbies and I found an example on the web. I will try Scripting.FileSystemObject.

Comment: Did test the "Scripting.FileSystemObject". It does work fine also. But according to this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906280/need-to-convert-text-files-to-unicode-from-utf8-in-vbscript)  ,  the "Scripting.FileSystemObject" does  not support "utf-8" character set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change to VbCrLf, but character naming should work if you do it in the right order.

Cr is ASCII(13) and Lf is ASCII(10) so your line ending should be

```
chr(13)&chr(10)
```