# Word VBA macro doesn't keep special characters

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that generates an input inbox, in which I type a text that is then appended into the word document

However, if I type special letters/characters into this box, they are not taken in account

Example: if I type "Dziękuję", the "ę" will be replaced by regular "e"

Is there a way I could update my code so that it accepts these kinds of characters ?

```
Sub WriteEngravingText()
WriteEngravingText Macro
Dim shp As Shape
Dim engravingL1 As String
Dim engravingL2 As String
Dim fontName As String
Dim filePath As String

For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
    
    If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
        shp.Select
        Selection.WholeStory
        engravingL1 = InputBox("First line : ", "Write")
        Selection.TypeText Text:=engravingL1
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        engravingL2 = InputBox("Second line: ", "Write")
        Selection.TypeText Text:=engravingL2
        fontName = InputBox("Font name : ", "Write")
        Selection.WholeStory
        Selection.Font.Name = fontName
        Selection.Font.Size = 11
        filePath = InputBox("File path : ", "Write")
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs fileName:=filePath
        Exit For
    End If
    
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this applies to your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376951/which-string-encoding-do-the-vba-built-in-file-operations-use

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not VBA itself, even if the VBA IDE cannot display those characters, it will deal with them correctly. Your problem is that the `InputBox`-Command cannot handle characters that are not part of the Code page of your computer. I havn't played with different settings for the system locale (as descibed in the [SO-Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40376951/7599798) that Piemol provided in the comments or on this [web page](https://www.spreadsheet1.com/how-to-display-foreign-characters-in-vbe.html)), but I strongly assume that once you change this setting to a code page containing the "ę", the correct character will be returned.

However, this will solve your problem only partly, first you need to be sure that all computers that runs your code will have the same definition, and you will hit the same problem once you need to add other characters that are not part of the choosen code page.

I therefore suggest that you create a simple Userform that simulates the VBA Inputbox. A textbox that is placed on a Userform can handle all the characters you need. The following example uses a form called `frmInputBox` that contains a label (lblPrompt), a textbox (tbInput) and 2 buttons for OK and cancel.

[image]

The code behind is simple.

```
Option Explicit

Private returnValue As String

Public Function InputBox(Prompt As String, Optional title As String = "Input", Optional defaultValue As String = "")
    Me.lblPrompt = Prompt
    Me.Caption = title
    Me.tbInput = defaultValue
    returnValue = ""
    Me.Show
    InputBox = returnValue
End Function

Private Sub btnCancel_Click()
    returnValue = ""
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub btnOK_Click()
    returnValue = Me.tbInput.Value
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

All you have to do now is to change the code of your routine to use the form instead of the VBA

```
 With New frmInputBox
    engravingL1 = .InputBox("First line : ", "Write")
    Selection.TypeText Text:=engravingL1
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    
    engravingL2 = .InputBox("Second line: ", "Write")
    Selection.TypeText Text:=engravingL2
        
    fontName = .InputBox("Font name : ", "Write", "Arial")
    If fontName <> "" Then
        Selection.WholeStory
        Selection.Font.Name = fontName
        Selection.Font.Size = 11
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Hi @FunThomas
I tried using your code and it doesn't understand the "Me" in the inputbox function

Comment: You need to put the code (the upper part) in the Code-Behind module of the form itself, not in a regular module.