# VBS open txt - save it with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: utf-8, vbscript

Hi I am sorry I cannot figure it out. I tried opening a txt changing its charset to UTF8 and save it under the same filename but that does not work.

```
Dim Dateisystem, Textdatei, text
Set Dateisystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Textdatei = Dateisystem.OpenTextFile("titel.txt")
text = Textdatei.ReadAll


Const adModeReadWrite = 3
Const adTypeText = 2
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

Sub SaveToFile(text, filename)
  With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    .Mode = adModeReadWrite
    .Type = adTypeText
    .Charset = "UTF-8"
    .Open
    .SaveToFile filename, adSaveCreateOverWrite
    .Close
  End With
End Sub

SaveToFile text, "titel.txt"
```

Comment: You need to close the file before you can (re)open it for writing (`Textdatei.Close`).

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
stream.Open
stream.Type = 2 'text
stream.Charset = "utf-8"
stream.LoadFromFile "C:\Your-File-Here(Input).txt"
text = stream.ReadText
stream.Close
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Your-File-Here(Output).txt", 2, True, True)
f.Write text
f.Close
```

Comment: Thank you. Although the chartset is set to utf-8 - the script converts ANSI into Unicode - what I would need is a UTF-8 encoded txt.

Comment: Maybe This Question Helpful For You [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906280/need-to-convert-text-files-to-unicode-from-utf8-in-vbscript)