# How to set Japanese characters(UTF-8) in VBScript variables

Tags: vbscript, character-encoding

I have a script where I need to set some Japanese text to a variable. But since vbscript is not supporting japanese texts, it get converted to some garbled text like `ãƒˆã‚³ã‚¸ãƒ£ãƒ‘ãƒ³ã‹ã‚‰ã®æ–°è¦æ³¨æ–‡`. My actual japanese text is `トコジャパンからの新規注文`.

My script will look like below

```
dim emlObj
set emlObj = CreateObject("EMailObject")
emlObj.Subject = "Train - New Orders From Costco Japan | コストコジャパンからの新規注文"
emlObj.Body = "Some japanese body text"
emlObj.Send()
```

I do not have any other options like storing this text in file or db and process in some other scripts as of now. since this script will be used by our customers and they will set their expected email body text. We'll use them for sending it as a mail.

I've also tried ADODB.Steam but that works only when reading the text from file.

Can someone please suggest a way to set the japanese text in vbscript?.

Edit:
To put a clarity on what i really needed.
**I want to hard-code a japanese text to a variable in VBScripts.**

Comment: What is `CreateObject("EMailObject")`, looks to be a custom COM component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to convert text files to Unicode from UTF8 in vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906280/need-to-convert-text-files-to-unicode-from-utf8-in-vbscript)

Comment: @Lankymart Yes, thats a custom object created for sending email. But the problem is not around that object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

```
Dim objStream, body, subject
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.CharSet = "utf-8"
objStream.Open
objStream.WriteText "Subject in Japanese"
objStream.SaveToFile "C:\Subject.txt", 2
objStream.Close
objStream.Open
objStream.WriteText "Body in Japanese"
objStream.SaveToFile "C:\body.txt", 2
objStream.Close
objStream.CharSet = "utf-8"
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile "C:\Body.txt"
body = objStream.ReadText()
objStream.Close
objStream.CharSet = "utf-8"
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile "C:\Subject.txt"
subject = objStream.ReadText()
objStream.Close
' Now body is stored in body variable and subject is in subject now do anything with them
```

Comment: The moment i set the japanese text in the code 
`objStream.WriteText "Subject in Japanese"`, it gets converted to a garbled text. So, i need a way to set the japanese text directly into vbscript's variable

Comment: @Dhaya you haven't explained what `EmailObject` is after being [asked in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59646838/how-to-set-japanese-charactersutf-8-in-vbscript-variables#comment105461662_59646838), how do you expect us to help if you won't answer queries? The likelihood is the COM component you instantiate is not handling UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Its not the custom object thats causing a problem. Even if i take that object off, and try to assign a japanese text directly to a variable in vbscript, it would fail.

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTANT: Since you are not using ADODB.Stream to load your content, then be sure to save your actual VBScript file as **UTF-16 LE** encoding.  Your script may optionally benefit from a Unicode byte-order-mark (**BOM**) header, as well -- depending upon how the VBScript engine and EmailObject respond.

Once the VBScript file is in the proper encoding, this script works fine for me:

```
With CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    With .Configuration.Fields
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")  = "smtp.somemailserver.net"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 10 
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        .Update
    End With

    .BodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
    .BodyPart.ContentTransferEncoding = "base64"

    .TextBody = "コストコジャパンからの新規注文"
    .TextBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"

    .HTMLBody = "<p>コストコジャパンからの新規注文</p>"
    .HTMLBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"

    .From = "me@somemailserver.net"
    .To = "you@somemailserver.net"
    .Subject = "Train - New Orders From Costco Japan | コストコジャパンからの新規注文"

    .Send()
End With
```

Note: I am using **CDO.Message** above, not **EmailObject**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried converting my script file to utf-16 LE but that didn't work either. Can you please tell me how did you set the file encoding type as UTF-16 LE for your script?

Comment: With a decent text editor.  I used TextPad, but Notepad++ and others will do the trick, as well.